# Can multiple friends ask my leaving villager to move to their islands?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

If I have a villager in boxes, and I invite multiple friends to my island, can they each invite that villager to their islands? Or will the villager only move in with the first friend who invites him?

Answer (score 1):

Only the first friend will be able to invite the villager. Once the dialogue is complete for the villager to move to the first friends island, your other friends won't be able to invite the villager anymore.